# SSD and RAM Upgrade Recommendation

Tags: laptop, ssd, compatibility, upgrade

I have a **Lenovo V14 G2 ITL** laptop and I want to upgrade my RAM and SSD at the same time. But, you know, these compatibility stuff may seem a bit messy. I have attached some info regarding the compatibilities from a document I find on the net.
So, for the ram: According to RAMExpert the current RAM's product code is: Micron **4ATF1G64HZ-3G2E1** respecting to it, will this Crucial RAM be appropriate: (code) [CT8G4SFRA32A](https://www.hepsiburada.com/crucial-ntb-8gb-3200mhz-ddr4-ct8g4sfra32a-p-HBV000019CMAG)? Also, how much impact would the latency difference make; could it harm the motherboard?

(Currently there is only 2242 256 GB SSD on the computer.) Secondly, for the SSD, although it looks like the computer fits with hard drive, I want to continue with SSD, so is it possible to connect a SSD to a 2.5" port which is apparently for an HDD. So, considering the image below (Laptop is 38Wh) would you recommend this: Kioxia Sata3 2.5" NAND - [LTC10Z480GG8](https://www.hepsiburada.com/kioxia-exceria-480gb-555mb-540mb-s-sata3-2-5-3d-nand-ssd-ltc10z480gg8-p-HBV00000U34M1) is it compatible? (This could be an awkward question, but I want to make sure.)

[image: The information about storage support. Mine is 38Wh model.]

Answer (score 0):

I'm only gonna give a partial answer since RAM upgradability on those cheaper laptops is kinda hit or miss, since some laptops (like my dads) uses soldered RAM, which is impossible to upgrade without buying a new laptop.

For SSD, any kind of 2.5in disk will work, which is the crappy hard drive Lenovo sells, your Kioxia drive, the Crucial MX500 (which is my favorite btw), the Kingston A400, the list goes on and on. Here is a list of the most popular SSDs within the Benelux that fit your laptop: https://tweakers.net/solid-state-drives/vergelijken/#filter:FYxBCsIwEEXvMusuEq0RcgB3rrKULkL61YGhDUksYsndna4-7z94O-Gb5DNjDu81V_IPa9xlnAbiZUNpxxsgSI3XhfwzSsVAOb4Q-Afy1hjFwgl3Vq9QM9KNpaFobSdn3fnYLYrGyZ5Gc6Wp9_4H